# How to adjust Elasticseach search scores?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

OK, so I'm migrating to Elasticsearch, and I haven't found a way to adjust the scores other than touching the source code (which is an option, but I want to know if there's a better way) or querying 1000's of results and sorting them afterwards (which is not).

A few cases:

1)

result A:

```
{
   "type":"project",
   "title":"foobar"
}
```

result B:

```
{
    "type":"bug",
    "title":"#foobar something is broken"
}
```

=> I would need to prioritize result A heavily so that query foobar always returns the corresponding project first instead of hundreds of bug reports that happen to have foobar in the title (quite typical case because reasons).

2)

result A:

```
{
    "type":"bug",
    "title":"#foobar something is broken",
    "status":"done"
}
```

result B:

```
{
    "type":"bug",
    "title":"#foobar something else is broken",
    "status":"todo"
}
```

=> Results with certain statuses should be prioritized, as in B >> A in this case.

3)

result A:

```
{
    "type":"bug",
    "title":"#foobar something is broken",
    "priority":"critical"
}
```

result B:

```
{
    "type":"bug",
    "title":"#foobar something else is broken",
    "priority":"low"
}
```

=> A >> B obviously.

etc

If it helps, I can also generate some static search score for items that Elasticsearch could use for sorting, eg.

```
{
    "type":"bug",
    "title":"#foobar something else is broken",
    "priority":"low".
    "searchscore":"420"
}
```

It does not catch all the complexity in the result comparison logic, but it would be a close enough solution, if it'd be noticeably easier to implement.

Comment: This sounds like a situation where you want things sorted somehow. Would it be enough to sort the docs on `type`, then on `priority` etc, rather than trying to score them differently?

Comment: @AndreiStefan there isn't really a clear hierarchy between the sort criterions, so not really.

Comment: Also, found something pretty promising: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-function-score-query.html . Will post an answer once I get it figured out.